# Userimage in Sharepoint Blog comment

Tags: sharepoint, comments

I´m searching for a way to display the userimage next to the name of a Blog-comment in sharepoint 07. First idea was to add a Image column  to the comment list and use a add event to fill it, but this would not catch a change of the userimage and I still have no control over the rendering.

Thanks for any suggestion

ren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a long Story short , there seems to be no simple Solution to achieve this.
The Listview for the comments can not be bend to show userimages.
Finally I had to create a own webpart to show the Post and the corresponding comments, but be warned. You have to search all comments associated with the Post and get the Userprofile for each user that left a comment.
Even I get Linq to work with MOSS07 the performance for large Blogs might suffer