# Create a Sharepoint Blog comment in code

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have the need to create Sharepoint blog comments by code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        sw.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPList spList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Kommentare"];
        SPListItem listItem = spList.Items.Add();
        listItem[listItem.Fields["Titel des Beitrags"].InternalName] = SPContext.Current.Item["Title"];
        listItem[listItem.Fields["Titel"].InternalName] = titlearea.Value;
        listItem[listItem.Fields["Textkörper"].InternalName] = CommentArea.Value;
        listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = curUser;
        //listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified] = curUser;
        listItem.Update();
        //spList.Update();
        sw.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    });
```

but I always get a "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only"

I tried Systemupdate and the values seem to be valid.

Comment: Ok, the Posttitle is a SPLookupField, hand has to be filled by: "#{ID};{Title}"
Last problem is that the Webpage reloads, before the entry is in the Comment List :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the Posttitle is a SPLookupField, and has to be filled by: "{ID}#;{Title}"

Answer (score 1):

I think the **Author** field is readonly and sharepoint automattically asign the loggined user name there.

So could you try it after commenting the line  `listItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = curUser;`

Comment: Thanks, but sadly makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is unrelated to your problem but you are creating the SPWeb object (or using the context) ***outside*** the delegate, if a user without proper privileges runs the code, it will not elevate properly. Do something like this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate {
using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
using (SPWeb elevatedSite = elevatedSite.RootWeb)
{

//impl

}});
```

Answer (score 0):

listItem[listItem.Fields["Titel des Beitrags"].InternalName] = SPContext.Current.Item["Title"];

Does SPContext.Current.Item point to a refence to the blog post you are adding the comment to?

By this I mean is your code running in a custom web part that replaces the standard "Add comments" web part on a blog post?

Comment: Yes it does.
According to the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769612/userimage-in-sharepoint-blog-comment I had to re implement the blog show Webpart, but let the original Post-Comment Part in place.
Unfortunately by this the page refresh after a comment post leads back to the page before the Comment is pushed into the List.

Answer (score 0):

This works, verified

```
    public static void AddComment(string url)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
        {
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList commentList = web.Lists["Comments"];
                SPListItem newItem = commentList.AddItem();
                newItem["Body"] = "body";
                newItem["Title"] = "title";
                newItem["PostTitle"] = "2;#post1";
                newItem.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

You may be writing a read-only field, like Author.